# Publish clicked point in Rviz without using navigation stack

Tags: ros, navigation, rviz, ros-kinetic, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wish to publish the clicked point in Rviz. I read that we need to be using the ROS navigation stack for this feature to work. However, my setup doesn't use laser scans and relies on aruco markers. Hence, I am not using the navigation stack.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329019/publish-clicked-point-in-rviz-without-using-navigation-stack/) by [Junskter](https://answers.ros.org/users/43698/junskter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2019-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You do not need to be using the ROS navigation stack. Just have your software subscribe to the topic that rviz is publishing for clicked points.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Junskter](https://answers.ros.org/users/43698/junskter/) on 2019-07-21**:
That was simple and it worked. Thanks!
You may add that as an answer if you like.